# Azure Function to get OAUth 2.0 token not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-functions

I am following this tutorial:

[Access Google Analytics with Azure Data Factory](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/access_google_analytics_with_azure_data_factory)

What I am struggling with is the Azure function.

This is the .net / C# code:

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
 
namespace GoogleAnalytics
{
    public class GetOAuthToken
    {
        [FunctionName("GetOAuthToken")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            var kvClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KEY_VAULT_URL")), new ManagedIdentityCredential());
            string keyJson = kvClient.GetSecret("KEY_VAULT_URL").Value.Value;
 
            var cred = GoogleCredential.FromJson(keyJson).CreateScoped(new string[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" });
            var token = await cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
 
            return new OkObjectResult("{\"token\":\"" + token + "\"}");
        }
    }
}
```

I create a new Azure Function App in Azure Portal with the following parameters:

Publish: Code
Runtime Stack: .NET
Version: 3.1
Region: Germany

I click on Code + Test and paste the code into the window.

If I run the code I get this errors:

```
2021-10-12T18:22:13  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2021-10-12T18:22:13.229 [Error] run.csx(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.291 [Error] run.csx(7,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.376 [Error] run.csx(17,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpTriggerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.432 [Error] run.csx(17,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpTrigger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.514 [Error] run.csx(17,26): error CS0103: The name 'AuthorizationLevel' does not exist in the current context
2021-10-12T18:22:13.572 [Error] run.csx(17,62): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.640 [Error] run.csx(19,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SecretClient' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.720 [Error] run.csx(19,111): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ManagedIdentityCredential' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2021-10-12T18:22:13.804 [Error] run.csx(22,24): error CS0103: The name 'GoogleCredential' does not exist in the current context
2021-10-12T18:22:13.826 [Warning] warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' used by 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core' matches identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=3.1.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb12334449ddae60' of 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions', you may need to supply runtime policy
2021-10-12T18:22:13.850 [Error] Executed 'Functions.GetOAuth' (Failed, Id=9990a123-3fb8-4a3e-8346-260e03bb303a, Duration=1267ms)Script compilation failed.
```

Do I need to install any packages inside my Azure tenant or do I need to do anything else beforehand?

And from where does the function know with secret and which key vault to use? Do I need to replace a placeholder within this code? The tutorial is not very specific in this regard.

Comment: What nuget packages do you have installed? My guess is that you don't have any, and the guide indirectly tells you to get "Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2".

Comment: Ok, I dont know anything about nuget packages. I guess this is the problem. I ll read about it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The procedure looks good from the tutorial which you have shared, looking at your stack trace all the modules which you have imported were missing.

Make sure you sign-in to [Visual Studio code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-runtime-functions-v3) and import all the packages and add Azure Core service extension, Install Azure functions extension.

[image]

Test the function from the local and deploy it to your function app. After deployment add all the local settings to application settings under Configurations in Azure function app portal.

[image]

Comment: I created the function in Visual Studio, added all dependencies etc and I could deploy it in Azure as a Function. The only problem is now, I get an HTTP 500 error. And I have no idea why.

Comment: This usually occurs when Azure service cannot connect to other service.. Make sure you check all the connection strings are valid in Application Settings in Configuration. In your case looks like you are storing connections using key vault, so for this you need to create an Access Policy in KeyVault Configuration, so that Azure functions applications can read the values from keyvault.

Comment: What should happen if I run the code of the function locally in my Visual Studio? Should it connect to Google and retrieve a token? I m not sure if the code works properly. I had some issues with the rights and access policy etc. but I think I got that right now. And I think the HTTP 500 is the response of the Google Analytics server.

Comment: I went over all settings, policies etc. and this is the errror I keep getting: 
Call to provided Azure function 'GetOAuthToken' failed with status-'InternalServerError' and message - 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

Comment: I got a bit further. Now I get this Error: 2021-10-14T11:46:03.111 [Error] Executed 'GetOAuthToken' (Failed, Id=83cf6460-fef2-4b5e-b8fc-23f06a728bac, Duration=2ms)Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')

Comment: "Value cannot be null" is because you are not specifying something which is related to your function. Now recheck all the appsettings once.. And I still suspect there is an issue with KeyVault settings. Make sure you create Access Policy in the KeyVault Config by using Managed-Identity Object and add the access policy in appsettings. Refer this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/simplifying-security-for-serverless-and-web-apps-with-azure-functions-and-app-service/